# Ajax can't catch PHP response on console log

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to send json data with ajax to php file. The query runs ok, but, when i try to catch the response on console, this shows me the same html where javascript is running and not the server response.

Until two days, i'd working with PHP 5.4. and then update to PHP 7 but the problem persists.

Apache => 2.4.39
PHP => 7.1.30
MySQL => 5.7.26
Architecture => x86_64

This is my javascript code

```
$('#check_usuario').submit(function() {
    var formData = { 'user': $('#user').val(), 'pass': $('#pass').val() }
    $.post('admin/validate.php', formData, response);           
    return false;
    function response(data){ // Recibimos la respuesta 'r' del servidor     
        $('#response').html('<p>User is ' + data);
        console.log(data);
                }
});
```

And this is PHP code

```php
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    header('Location: ../login.html');
}
else {
include('conection.php');
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$resp = array( "user" => $user, "pass" => $pass );
echo json_encode($resp);
die($conexion);
}
```

I expect get the user and pass value, but console prints the html document where ajax is executing

Comment: Your not sending the submit so it's sending the login.hrml

Comment: There's no `submit` key in your request, so it's following the redirection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're checking for a POST value:

```
if(!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

But you're not sending that POST value:

```
var formData = { 'user': $('#user').val(), 'pass': $('#pass').val() }
```

So the result is the redirect header:

```
header('Location: ../login.html');
```

Either remove the `if` condition, or send the value:

```
var formData = { 'user': $('#user').val(), 'pass': $('#pass').val(), 'submit': true }
```